# Want to understand differential equations...how to solve this basic differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I put the differential equation $y' = xy$ into Wolfram Alpha and it tells me the solution is
$$y(x) = c_1\,e^\frac{x^2}{2}$$

- Can anybody explain to me how to sub this back into the original equation so as to verify it is the solution?
- And was the solution arrived at in the first place?

I really need to get a differntial equations book out of the library and go through it, which is what I plan to do at xmas when I have the time...but in the meantime I would appreciate if someone could explain this particular problem to me as it is starting to annoy me that I don't understand this stuff when doing numerical analysis (even though we can get by without knowing it).

Comment: You must mean $y=c_1e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}$. It is easy to check that this works by differentiating. We get $y'=c_1xe^{x^2/2}$ (Chain Rule), which is indeed equal to $xy$.  This is an example of a *separable* DE.

Comment: The important thing is that, supposing $y(x)>0$ (or $<0$) in a vicinity of $x$, you can divide both sides of the ode by $y$ and use the chaing rule to write the left side as (case $y >0$) $$
\frac{d}{dx} \log \big(y(x)\big)
$$ and integrate both sides of the equation. Why don't you do the case $y<0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check it's a solution: find $y'=dy/dx$, and check that it takes the value of $xy$. If it does, it's a solution.

You solve an equation like that by a method known as seperation of variables, which you should be able to find some lecture notes on by googleing. In this example:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=xy\Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{y}\frac{dy}{dx}=x\Leftrightarrow\int\frac{1}{y}\frac{dy}{dx}{dx}=\int x\ dx$$
$$\Leftrightarrow\int \frac{dy}{y}=\frac{x^{2}}{2}+c\Leftrightarrow ln(y)=\frac{x^{2}}{2}+c $$

Then exponentiating, we get that the solution is $y=e^{x^{2}/2 + c}=Ae^{x^{2}/2}$, where the constant $A$ is $A=e^{c}$.

Comment: Cheers...edited comment.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{dy}{dx} = xy$.
$\frac{dy}{y} = xdx$.
Integrating the both sides, we get
log $y = \frac{x^2}{2} + c$.
Hence $y = e^c e^\frac{x^2}{2}$.